# Variable keeps turning into an object instead of an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I'm learning javascript (and HTML on Electron), and I have a variable which is meant to be an array:

```
var arrayList = [];
```

When I add objects to it (taken from JSON data), using Push:

```
arrayList.push(object);
```

Everything works perfect. I then save this using an api from npm called: electron-json-storage

I then want to pull this data, push an object into it and save it back. The problem is when I use the api to obtain the data to save into the variable arrayList, it turns arrayList into an object, it then errors out when I try to push to it as it is the wrong variable type now compared to before.

Would love any help and guidance would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code where you push and pull the data using your library ?

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to *parse* the API response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apologies about this, turns out the 'electron-json-storage' api sends back a blank object if the file doesn't exist, which was actually my problem (even though I know I didn't write that above) and what kept turning it into an object. I wouldn't of figured it out without re-looking over my code before posting here (so thanks klugjo) and for trying to parse the object which double confirmed it was an object and lead me to find the actual problem (So thanks so much Robert).

Again thanks all for the help!